# event.getX not corresponding with getLayoutX for circle

Tags: java, javafx, nodes

I'm trying to create a program that creates an instance of circle which gets the x and y coordinates of the mouseclick. However when trying to get the x for the circle it seems to be equal to 0.

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            final Circle newCircle = getCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 30);
            pane.getChildren().addAll(newCircle);
            final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                double deltaX = 2;
                double deltaY = 2;
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    newCircle.setLayoutX(newCircle.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
                    newCircle.setLayoutY(newCircle.getLayoutY() + deltaY);

                    final Bounds bounds = pane.getBoundsInLocal();
                    final boolean atRightBorder = newCircle.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX()-newCircle.getRadius());
                    final boolean atLeftBorder = newCircle.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX()+newCircle.getRadius());
                    final boolean atBottomBorder = newCircle.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMinY()+newCircle.getRadius());
                    final boolean atTopBorder = newCircle.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY()-newCircle.getRadius());
                    if(atRightBorder || atLeftBorder)
                        deltaX *= -1;
                    if(atBottomBorder ||atTopBorder)
                        deltaY *= -1;
                }
            }));
            loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            loop.play();
```

The line i'm focusing on is this one:

```
final Circle newCircle = getCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 30);
            System.out.print(newCircle.getLayoutX());
```

Where i get the print out "0.0" even though the event.getX parameter is different.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Edit: getCircle():

```
 private Circle getCircle(double x, double y, double r){
    final Circle newCircle = new Circle(x, y, r);
    return newCircle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor you are calling is implemented as such:

```
public Circle(double centerX, double centerY, double radius) {
    setCenterX(centerX);
    setCenterY(centerY);
    setRadius(radius);
}
```

Where `setCenterX()` has the implementation:

```
public final void setCenterX(double value) {
    if (centerX != null || value != 0.0) {
        centerXProperty().set(value);
    }
}
```

`getLayoutX()` is accessing the `layoutX` property, which haven't been set by the constructor, hence it returns `0.0`:

```
public final double getLayoutX() {
    return layoutX == null ? 0.0 : layoutX.get();
}
```

You need to set the `layoutX` property, like you already do in your code:

```
newCircle.setLayoutX(newCircle.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
```

Comment: I seem to have fixed this issue by using relocate(event.getX(),event.getY()) instead. But your solution worked as well! thanks! 

I seem to have another issue where my bounds maxX and Y are actually updating even though i set it to final.